# convert date from DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS to 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I am using Oracle 11G and I want to convert my date format shown below
FROM 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS' to 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS

Please suggest a way.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you have dates saved in a table, and are they in DATE data type? If so, displaying the date in whatever format can be done either with explicit use of TO_CHAR(...) with the proper format model (the one you desire), or else Oracle will convert to string for you, using the value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Are you asking how to write TO_CHAR(...) wrapper, or how to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT? Or is the data **not** in the DATE data type to begin with?

Comment: There are no dates "shown below". Did you intend to add more information?